# apt-get reports "dpkg: cycle found while processing triggers"

Tags: 16.04, command-line, apt, updates, dpkg

In my other question about how to [Suppress command line questions during package installation](https://askubuntu.com/q/1152915/) I found an answer. Unfortunately I'm already stuck with the next problem.

The `apt-get` command (to be more precise: `dpkg`, which is called by `apt-get`) faces the problem of recursive triggers:

```
[...]
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.12) ...
[...]
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.12) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-135-generic
[...]
Preparing to unpack .../initramfs-tools_0.122ubuntu8.14_all.deb ...
Unpacking initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.14) over (0.122ubuntu8.12) ...
[...]
Preparing to unpack .../ca-certificates_20170717~16.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates (20170717~16.04.2) over (20170717~16.04.1) ...
[...]
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.14) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
[...]
Setting up ca-certificates (20170717~16.04.2) ...
[...]
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.14) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-135-generic
dpkg: cycle found while processing triggers:
 chain of packages whose triggers are or may be responsible:
  initramfs-tools -> ca-certificates
 packages' pending triggers which are or may be unresolvable:
  ca-certificates: update-ca-certificates
  resolvconf: resolvconf-enable-updates
  initramfs-tools: update-initramfs
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
 triggers looping, abandoned
Processing triggers for resolvconf (1.78ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.14) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-135-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates
W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Somehow I don't get it as `ca-certificates` doesn't refer `initramfs-tools` (at least not as far as I can tell).

I logged-in manually in that system and performed the same `apt-get` call using the `--fix-broken` option. Somehow that fixed the problem.

I implemented that in my updater program, so `apt-get` is executed with that option right from the spot. But I keep getting the same error. Meaning that option may fix the problem afterwards, but not during the update process.

Does anyone know a way to prevent that problem from happening?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found out that this is just a subsequent error of another problem I had. The packages I installed / updated had a dependency problem. Since I solved that everything works fine.

I also think there wouldn't have been any solution to this problem.